# why the variable need't be defined in the Scala codes?

Tags: scala

I am a Scala beginner. I saw this codes in **STEP 7. PARAMETERIZE ARRAYS WITH TYPES** of **Programming in Scala, 3rd Edition 2**.

```
val greetStrings = new Array[String](3)
greetStrings(0) = "Hello"
greetStrings(1) = ", "
greetStrings(2) = "world!\n"
for (i <- 0 to 2)
    print(greetStrings(i))
```

I can't understand "i" needn't be defined. When I write some codes like that:

```
val greetStrings = new Array[String](3)
greetStrings(0) = "Hello"
greetStrings(1) = ", "
greetStrings(2) = "world!\n"
var i
for (i <- 0 to 2)
    print(greetStrings(i))
```

Code error appears:

```
/Users/tianci/Desktop/helloworld.scala:6: error: '=' expected but ';' found.
for (i <- 0 to 2)
^
one error found
```

Comment: Please first have a look at a Scala tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can define `i` without `val` or `var` because it is valid syntax defined by the language specification.

When you use for comprehenssion in Scala, the compiler turns it into a sequence of `foreach`, `map` or `flatMap` calls. This means that

```
for (i <- 0 to 2)
```

Is turned into:

```
scala.Predef.intWrapper(0).to(2).foreach(i => print(greetStrings(i)))
```

Which you can see defines `i` only in the scope of `foreach`, and is used only to create a function instance and nothing else.

---

`var i` is a variable declaration without a type, which is a compile time error in Scala. You need to tell the compiler what type it is expected to be, and initialize it:

```
var i = 0
for (i <- 0 to 2)
    print(greetStrings(i))
```

Or even better:

```
greetStrings.foreach(println)
```

Comment: But in for loop of the first code, "i" doesn't seem to been defined.